# iOS crashes with Please register custom URL scheme but already added

Tags: ios, react-native

My iOS app crashes and sentry shows the error was `Please register custom URL scheme 'app-1-xxx-ios-xxx' in the app's Info.plist file.`.
However, I DID add it. When I open the `.ipa` bundle I uploaded to the app store. Renamed to zip, opened the content of the app in Payload and opened Info.plist in xcode.
Under URL Types I clearly see under one of the items a URL Scheme with the one they ask for.
Furthermore. When I build the same app for internal distribution (testing), install on the phone and test - it works and doesn't fail.
Anyone knows what is going on and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the correct custom URL scheme? The correct URL is located in GoogleService-info.plist with the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID key.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer to me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32037101)